# Can to execute function before download in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have a file to download.

```
<a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>
```

I want to execute several commands before the download starts, is there any method to do this?

I checked the manual for a tag, there's no option like onclick or before_click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked the manual for a tag, there's no option like onclick or before_click.

Of course `a` elements have a `click` event; all elements that take up page real-estate do.

The click handler is run, synchronously, before the default action of the link is performed. So any work you need to do before the download starts you can do in the click handler:

```
document.querySelector("...selector for the link...").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Do your stuff here
});
```

If what you need to do includes *asynchronous* processing, then you'll need to prevent the default action and (try to) trigger that action again later:

```
var triggering = false;
document.querySelector("...selector for the link...").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (triggering) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = this;
    startTheAsyncProcess(function() {
        // Async callback: Do your stuff here...
        // ...then try to trigger its action
        triggering = true;
        link.click();
        triggering = false;
    });
});
```

Depending on what your async work is, you may or may not be able to trigger the download; the browser may decide it's not being initiated by a user action and prevent it.

Comment: Hi, thnx for the answer. It seems after I prevent the default action, I cannot start the download. I mean is there a way to manually start the download or register this behavior to the handler? Like "this.download"?

Comment: @J.R.: Yeah, I suspected that would be the case if you were doing something asynchronous. Unsurprisingly, browsers are pretty careful not to allow web pages to initiate downloads except in direct response to a user action. You're doing something asynchronous, then?

Comment: yea, pretty much, I have to prepare the source for the download in the backend then after it's been prepared I will send a signal then start the download. Now I got stuck at the point of how to make this a tag work as I want it to be...

Comment: I am stupid, now I understood the meaning of the boolean triggering.

Comment: @J.R.: I'm sure you're not stupid, we all miss things sometimes! Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder, 
I'm looking to use your example in a dynamics portal to call a workflow BEFORE the download takes places. so on the webpage I. If using the above async code (MS flow works async), what would then be the selector for the link? 
var triggering = false;
document.querySelector('a.entitylist-download').addEventListenier("click", function () {
 if(triggering){return;} 
 e.preventDefault();
 var link = this;
 CreatePortalDownload(function() {
  triggering = true;
  link.click();
  triggering = false;
  });
});
Where CreatePortaldownload is my function to call a MS Flow.

Comment: @TimHage - I'm afraid I don't understand the question. I'm not sure what it being async has to do with the selector....?

Comment: He @T.J.Crowder, thanks for the quick response. Well Async has to do with MS Flow that I will trigger later. Though I'm totally new to DOM, so I don't have a clue what to use in a "... selector for the link...". I tried to download-as-excel link, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: @TimHage - The selector will be really specific to your page. Right-click the link and look at its attributes (in particular `id` and `class` if any, but also others) and those of its parent and other ancestors. Then you can use [any CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to find that element in the DOM. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The code where it dit work (and where I use $(document).ready(function(){......} you can find in the link below. Though there the download takes place before the HTTP call to a flow. Curious if you know how to do the HTTP request before the download. Lots of love, Tim https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Track-downloads-of-Entity-Lists-from-the-portal/m-p/1681610/highlight/true#M427918

Comment: Oh you were too quick for me with reply. If I right click, and open inspect, all I can find is this:
<div class="input-group pull-left"><a href="#" class="entitylist-download btn btn-info pull-right action" title="Downloaden">Downloaden</a></div>
Does this mean that the class is "input-group pull-left"? But then what is it's ID? 
Getting closer, thanks a lot for your help already

Comment: @TimHage - If you want to target the download link, it would be the classes on the `a` element. So for instance, `a.entitylist-download.action` might select it (or there might be multiple of those). I don't see anything in that that seems likely to be *unique*, but it depends on what the page has on it (well, obviously, sorry :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

.preventDefault() would be a good place to start.  You can stop your link from performing its default behavior, inject whatever you want, and then later trigger the download.